# Pattern: How to access object.properties (correctly) from result returned by async function

Tags: javascript, error-handling, webstorm

I have a function that `fetch` data from DB or API point and add properties to it, like this:

```
async function function_one (arg) {
    try {
        if (arg != number) throw new Error('error')
        let data = await findOne(arg);
        data['property'] = 1+2+3
        ....
        return data //this is an object with it's own properties
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e); //errorHandling with winston
    }
}
```

and another (master) function that use data from previous function(s):

```
async function Master (user_input) {
    try {
        let object = await function_one(user_input);
        console.log(object.property_one) //weak warning
        let another_object = await another_function (fixed_arg);
        //some other logic with object properties.
        return result_data
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

So when I'm trying to access `object` properties in `Master` function like:

```
let object = await function_one(user_input);
console.log(object.property_one)
```

My IDE (WebStrom) shows something like that:[image] but I know that if `function_one` will execute correctly (w/o `catch` block) this property would exist. And if `Master` function will fail, user won't receive a message from `function_one`. (IDE says that `throw` exception caught locally).

So what am I doing wrong and what should I do? Handle every async function in `Master` function like that:

```
async function Master (user_input) {
    try {
        let object = await function_one(user_input)
            .then(data => {
                //working with properties here and then return it?
            })
            .catch(error => {//handle it});
```

or return from `function_one` all properties like: `return {property_one, property_two, ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) helps me with this problem